# Swift: performSegueWithIdentifier during unwind not working

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I've created a typical unwind flow from my view controller #2 to back to view controller #1 using a programmatically created button using the segue to Exit technique.

I have trace statements that confirm that the button code is executing perfectly and that the #2 **performSegueWithIdentifier** func is being called with the correct segue ID, but nothing happens.

**To clarify:**

I've connect the view controller #2 to the Exit and confirmed the segue ID is exact in all places. I traced the #2 identifier in the #2 **performSegueWithIdentifier** func and it matches perfectly.

As I understand it, I no longer need to use the **dispatch** fix with the current version of 2016 XCode. I tried it anyway and nothing worked. There is no crash, just no unwinding.

Somehow the unwind technique isn't reversing using this Exit technique. Any ideas?

I've been following the tutorial here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/

CODE VC #2:

```
// action func wired to button, fires perfectly
func unwind(seg:UIStoryboardSegue!) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwind", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have in vc1 and the code in vc2?

Comment: Not much to it. Both the above functions fire perfectly and trace out print statements with the exact segue names I've used. :( The only code in the V2 is the viewDidLoad function that doesn't fire at all.

Comment: you don't implement `performSegueWithIdentifier`; this is implemented by UIViewController. The IBActionMethod with a UIstoryboardSegue argument should be in VC1 (it has an empty implementation). You call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` in the button handler method which if you aren't using a storyboard doesn't need to have @IBAction

Comment: Ok, I tried as much of that as I understood and now it throws tons of errors, due to the lack of recognition of the segue assignments to the VCs. As I understand the unwind method is that I'm queuing a segue to the Exit of vc2 to simply "leave" the stage, thus returning the next VC in the stack which is VC1. I only used the performSegueWithIdentifier in VC2 to trace out the segue name. I removed the IBAction prefix.

Comment: Have demo with unwind segue,

Comment: Thank you for the clean link. Extremely helpful. I've always wanted to know how to do that just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VC1 you need a function:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

Then in your storyboard ctrl drag from the yellow view controller icon to the Exit icon and select `unwindToVC1:` from the pop up

Give the unwind segue an identifier, say `unwindToVC1`

Now, in VC2, create your button `touchUpInside` handler:

```
func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToVC1")
}
```

when you set up your button programatically, add this method as the action handler:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Ok, this makes complete sense to me, but now I'm getting a runtime error that the vc2 doesn't recognize the segue name from vc1.

Comment: You can ctrl-drag to exit in VC3 and select `unwindToVC1:` again and give that segue an identifier and it will work the same.  This tech note explains how unwind segues work https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Comment: I did that, but it creates a NEW instance of the VC1 that is blank. Does that sound right? I'm trying to take advantage of the previous rendering on VC1 and simply go back to it. Is that wrong?

Comment: OK, MISSING STEP: Add a CRT-DRAG-EXIT to the VC2 and point it to the VC1 segue. What the Apple docs mentioned was creating as many as one needs. That was it! Works great now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the `unwind` function to VC1. Leave that implementation empty or perhaps put a print statement to see if its coming to that function.
2. Make sure that in the storyboard there is a unwind segue created with identifier "unwind"
3. Add a button action func `buttonAction:(button:UIButton)` that calls `performSegueWithIdentifier("unwind"...)` in VC2.
4. Set the `buttonAction` as the action for the button created programatically.

Comment: How do I get VC2 to recognize the segue that only exists in VC1? I'm getting a runtime error of an unrecognized segue name.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Got it!